# Is there a way to make new columns from cells and have their values be from another column

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I am trying to find a way to take information from one column in a pandas DataFrame and have its unique value be the new column and its score be the value in the newly formed column. I.e.

| Index | Product | Test | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | Protection | 5 |
| 1 | A | Comfort | 6 |
| 2 | B | Protection | 6 |
| 3 | B | Comfort | 7 |

And the end result be something like this:

| Index | Product | Protection | Comfort | Test_C | Test_D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 5 | 6 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | B | 6 | 7 | 3 | 8 |

I am trying to do this to clean my data ready for machine learning. Test_C and Test_D were added to show that there are more than just 2 types of tests and it differs depending on the product what test is carried out.

I have tried to do it using the Pandas.get_dummies method but was wondering if there was a cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pivot()`:

`df.pivot(index = 'Product', columns = 'Test', values = 'Score')`

Returns:

```
Product Comfort Protection
A       6       5
B       7       6
```

If you want to have numerical index or keep 'Product' as a column instead of index, add `reset_index()`:

`df.pivot(index = 'Product', columns = 'Test', values = 'Score').reset_index()`

Returns:

```
    Product Comfort Protection
0   A       6       5
1   B       7       6
```